# Как заменить содержимое Frame

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно "MainWindow", в нем Frame "Go" в который при запуске окна помещается "Page1", в "Page1" еще один Frame "Main", в котором лежит "Page2".

Как при нажатии кнопки в "Page2" поместить Page3 в Frame "Go", при этом не создавая нового "MainWindow" ?

[image: MainWindow]

Comment: Пример с [навигацией](https://github.com/ClnViewer/SpchListBuilder/blob/02d27917b5f548726a466da186c240b15aff6c94/Metro/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L43) по страницам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать схему загрузки `Page` с помощью
`<Frame Element Name> .NavigationService.Navigate(pageClassHandle);`

Сравнивать текущую загруженную страницу можно таким способом:

**MainWindow.cs**

```
 Type t = 
  ContentFrame.NavigationService.Content.GetType();
 if (t == typeof(PageHandle))
     ...
```

и в xaml добавить примерно следующее:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Frame
         x:Name="ContentFrame"
         Margin="0,0,0,0"
         Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainWindow, Mode=OneWay}"
         NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow - условно главное окно WPF приложения.

Comment: а что написать в Button_Click на странице Page2 ?

Comment: Вариантов много, но обработчик фрейма живёт в MainWindow.* - как следствие смена страниц должна быть организована там, и из страниц уже можно звать разные функции по смене страниц расположенные в MainWindow.cs (условно)

Comment: И все же мне не понятно как при нажатии кнопки в Page2, сказать обработчику в MainWindow, что пора задуматься над сменой содержимого фрейма

Comment: Реализовать в MainWindow функцию по смене страниц. В функцию передавать например `enum` значение нужной страницы. Смена страниц производится в этой функции. А в класс всех страниц предавать `this` из MainWindow, что бы они могли обращаться к его функциям. Это как быстрый пример реализации.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться