# Как создать окно/страницу WPF с обобщением?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно создать окно или страницу, которая работала бы с указанным типом.

```
 public partial class FilterPage<T> : Page
```

Если это возможно, то как это сделать?

Мне нужно, чтобы в окне я мог сделать что-то вроде:

```
thisWindow.Content = new Page<MyType>();
```

Comment: Было же вроде только что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922432/Как-заменить-содержимое-frame/922435#922435

Comment: И в чем смысл? На самом деле WPF не очень хорошо дружит с дженериками, особенно в части XAML разметки

Comment: А какая ваша конечная цель? Вообще я очень советую вам перестать использовать Frame/Page и др. И перейти на реализацию с помощью `ContentPresenter`, а сам вид контента задавать через `DataTemplate`. Пример подобной реализации [ну очень простой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), а нервов и сил сбережете в дальнейшем уйму!